# decrement in MySQL to stop at 0

Tags: mysql, decrement

hey guys I have got a MySQL query that reduces stock every button click,

**Query**

```
UPDATE Animals 
   SET Stock = Stock - 1 
 WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'
```

problem is I wish for it to stop at 0 and not go into negative is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
 
 "UPDATE Animals SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}' and Stock >0"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE Animals
   SET Stock = Stock - 1
 WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}' AND Stock > 0
```

So restrict the row to have `Stock > 0` explicitly

Comment: Yep, like it better then my `IF(..)`

Comment: agreed I try not to use `IF(..)` unless I absolutely need to

Comment: Make sure you're checking the results (number of rows changed) to ensure that the item was actually in stock when the item was ordered.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent over-ordering, you might want to check to see if there's actually stock, hold it in reserve, then make your decision, by using a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT Stock
  FROM Animals
  WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}' AND Stock > 0
  FOR UPDATE;
```

If you didn't get a record, the stock is <= 0. If you get a record, you've got the remaining stock count.

Now update it:

```
 UPDATE Animals SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}';
 COMMIT;
```

Otherwise,

```
 ROLLBACK;
```

You'll want to do this over the same session (connection).

Comment: It would perfectly work even in non-transaction way. `UPDATE` would lock the row to update it, so there is no chance for 2 sessions to decrement the value in case if there is a `AND Stock > 0` predicate

Answer (score 0):

`... SET Stock = IF(Stock < 1, Stock, Stock -1)...`

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you want to decrement the inventory by more than one -

`'{2}'` here, refers to the quantity to be decremented.

```
UPDATE Animals
  SET Stock = Stock - '{2}'
  WHERE 
     Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}' 
     AND Stock - '{2}' >= 0
```